# javax.xml.validation.Validator very slow since JRE6 update 24?

Tags: xml, performance, validation, java

We hit an issue that the XML validator present in Java JRE got very slow in JRE 1.6u24 and this is present even in the most recent update.

Validating 1000 XMLs takes for us:

~1.4 seconds for version <= 1.6u23;
~15.2 seconds for versions >= 1.6u24

Which is 10 times slower! I tried to search if anyone found the issue already, but I can't find anything.

We can of course workaround it by using another library like woodstox, but we would prefer pure JRE and I can't believe this could be there for such a long time without any improvement being made...

The code we test looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new Source[] {
            new StreamSource(new File("schema1.xsd")),
            new StreamSource(new File("schema2.xsd")) });

    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    XMLInputFactory staxFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    String xml = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("to_validate.xml"), "UTF-8");

    Date start = new Date();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        XMLStreamReader xmlr = staxFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xml));
        StAXSource ss = new StAXSource(xmlr);
        validator.validate(ss);
    }
    Date end = new Date();

    System.out.println("seconds needed: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Woodstox includes an XSD validator; if you want an alternative, you could try the Apache version of Xerces (which is usually far better than the JDK version), or Saxon-EE.

The most likely reason for a slowdown like this is that you are fetching DTDs from the W3C web site. I don't know why this would change between JDK versions, but it is certainly something that changed about a year ago, when W3C took a policy decision to throttle requests for common DTDs by deliberately delaying the response. If this is the problem then the solution is to use a catalog to redirect access to a local copy; or if you use Saxon 9.4, it has copies of the most common DTDs built in.